# What does it mean for a category to have a semi-automorphism?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, semigroups, morphism

A while back, somebody asked me about why automorphisms are always isomorphisms.  I bobbled the question a bit.  Invertability is always one of those nice things that I take for granted.  But he got me wondering.  If I have a morphism whose source and target is the same class which is not invertable, what does that mean?  I even had to make up the name, semi-automorphism, stealing from the naming of a semigroup, since I could not find a term to describe such a morphism.

What would it mean if a category had such a morphism?  Being "structure" preserving, I naturally think of reduction rules in type theory, but is there a more fundamental definition for what they would mean?  And, ideally, I'd like to understand this in a way which explains why isomorphisms whose source and target are the same are common enough to earn so much attention in category theory while these non-invertible equivalents do not.

Comment: Are you thinking about endomorphisms? These are studied somewhat.

Comment: The usual name for what you called a "semi-automorphism" is "endomorphism".

Comment: Generally I think automorphisms are given more attention because they form a group. Automorphisms also tell you more about the "internal symmetries" of an object. For example in group theory if two subgroups are the image of each other with respect to an automorphism and its inverse, then the quotients by those subgroups are isomorphic. A particularly pathological phenomenon in group theory that you may wish to think about is that you can have surjective endomorphisms that are not automorphisms (ie aren't injective).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word you're looking for is "endomorphism", and it is not at all rare for a category to have endomorphisms which are not automorphisms. Consider, for example, the category of vector spaces with morphisms given by linear transformations - not every linear map from a vector space to itself is invertible (i.e., there are square matrices which are not invertible).